# Where clause between union all in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that vertically expands data by using Union condition. Below are the 2 sample tables:

```
create table #temp1(_row_ord int,CID int,_data varchar(10))

insert #temp1
values
(1,1001,'text1'),
(2,1001,'text2'),
(4,1002,'text1'),
(5,1002,'text2')


create table #temp2(_row_ord int,CID int,_data varchar(10))
insert #temp2
values
(1,1001,'sample1'),
(2,1001,'sample2'),
(4,1002,'sample1'),
(5,1002,'sample2')

--My query
select * from #temp1 
union
select * from #temp2 where CID in (select CID from #temp1)
order by _row_ord,CID

drop table #temp1,#temp2
```

So my current output is:

[image]

I want to group the details of every client together for which I am unable to use 'where' clause across Union condition.

My desired output:

[image]

Any help?! Order by is also not helping me.

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to use where clause across union condition?"

Comment: Union-All works when there are equivalent rows fetched from diff queries. You might want to check if temp1 and temp columns are same.

Comment: When I say where #temp1.CID = #temp2.CID its throwing me error saying 'The multi-part identifier "#temp1.cid" could not be bound.'

Comment: what kind of where do you need? It looks like you want ordered output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can imagine you want all of the rows for a `CID` sorted by `_row_ord` from the first table before the ones from the second table. And the `CID` should be the outermost sort criteria.

If that's right, you can select literals from your tables. Let the literal for the first table be less than that of the second table. Then first sort by `CID`, then that literal and finally by `_row_ord`.

```
SELECT cid,
       _data
       FROM (SELECT 1 s,
                    _row_ord,
                    cid,
                    _data
                    FROM #temp1
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 2 s,
                    _row_ord,
                    cid,
                    _data
                    FROM #temp2) x
       ORDER BY cid,
                s,
                _row_ord;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=4efba73930eadf32d8efd0494657107a)

Comment: So simple. Winner, winner, chicken dinner. +1.

Comment: Wondering how does this answer differ from mine :o Other than the obvious omitting of where clause

Comment: @KamilGosciminski: Yours is similar, but doesn't use the `_row_ord`.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your need, you need the output to be sorted the way that `#temp1` rows appear before `#temp2` rows for each `cid` value.

What you could do is generate additional column `ordnum` assigning values for each table, just for sorting purposes, and then get rid of it in the outer select statement.

```
select cid, _data
from (
  select 1 as ordnum, * 
  from #temp1 
  union all
  select 2 as ordnum, * 
  from #temp2 t2
  where exists (
    select 1
    from #temp1 t1
    where t1.cid = t2.cid
    )
  ) q
order by cid, ordnum
```

I have also rewritten your `where` condition for an equivalent which should work faster using `exists` operator.

[**Live DEMO - click me!**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b2455913da2cac0d91474294b8c9a367)

**Output**

```
cid     _data
1001    text1
1001    text2
1001    sample1
1001    sample2
1002    text1
1002    text2
1002    sample1
1002    sample2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use With. here is my first try with your sql

```
create table #temp1(_row_ord int,CID int,_data varchar(10))

insert #temp1
values
(1,1001,'text1'),
(2,1001,'text2'),
(4,1002,'text1'),
(5,1002,'text2')


create table #temp2(_row_ord int,CID int,_data varchar(10))
insert #temp2
values
(1,1001,'sample1'),
(2,1001,'sample2'),
(4,1002,'sample1'),
(5,1002,'sample2');

WITH result( _row_ord, CID,_data) AS
(
--My query
select * from #temp1 
union
select * from #temp2 where CID in (select CID from #temp1)


)
select * from tmp order by CID ,_data
drop table #temp1,#temp2
```

result

```
_row_ord    CID _data
1   1001    sample1
2   1001    sample2
1   1001    text1
2   1001    text2
4   1002    sample1
5   1002    sample2
4   1002    text1
5   1002    text2
```

Comment: Results aren't in the right order. Compare to the desired result in the question. (Similar to the problem I'm having, actually.)

Comment: made some changes and added result, look at it agin if it wrong the i would delete my answer as it dose not work as u which

Answer (score -1):

Union is placed between two result set blocks and forms a single result set block. If you want a where clause on a particular block you can put it:

```
select a from a where a = 1
union
select z from z


select a from a
union
select z from z where z = 1


select a from a where a = 1
union
select z from z where z = 1
```

The first query in a union defines column names in the output. You can wrap an output in brackets, alias it and do a where on the whole lot:

```
select * from
(
  select a as newname from a where a = 1
  union
  select z from z where z = 2
) o
where o.newname = 3
```

It is important to note that a.a and z.z will combine into a new column, o.newname. As a result, saying `where o.newname` will filter on all rows from both a and z (the rows from z are also stacked into the newname column). The outer query knows only about o.newname, it knows nothing of a or z

Side note, the query above produces nothing because we know that only rows where a.a is 1 and z.z is 2 are output by the union as o.newname. This o.newname is then filtered to only output rows that are 3, but no rows are 3

```
select * from
(
  select a as newname from a
  union
  select z from z
) o
where o.newname = 3
```

This query will pick up any rows in a or z where a.a is 3 or z.z is 3, thanks to the filtering of the resulting union